# vertical-align and background-position CSS not working with JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to vertically crop an image inside a div and I'm having trouble getting the vertical-align and background-position styles to register and work...

I've tried using vertical-align, background-position, background-position-y, I've tried calling the background image url inline in style, and nothing is working correctly...

The images are being called in the HTML within a js file:

```
<div class="product-image-wrap" data-slider-quickview="">
      <img src="${result[i].images[0].src}" class="variant-image-${result[i].images[0].id}" alt="">
 </div>
```

and the CSS is as follows:

```
  .product-image-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }

    .product-image-wrap .img {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 170px;
      vertical-align: middle;
       }
```

Comment: adding minimal working code here will help us understand your problem and requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want to achieve, maybe you want to change the height of the wrapper but contain the aspect ratio of the image? In this case you can use `object-fit: cover;` on the image, then you can change the height of the wrapper div freely:

```css
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 18px;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/Acute-Dog-Diarrhea-47066074.jpg">    
 </div>
```